# Can i use OSX native API's in electron

Tags: macos, cross-platform, electron

Is there a way to use OSX Native API's using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io). Let say i want to use [System Configuration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001027), is there a way to use the power of native OSX API?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I realize this is a late answer but you have some options:

- [native node modules](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) allow you to write in C++ and ObjectiveC (or Swift) and expose an API to node.js using v8. This gives you a lot of flexibility and power but requires the most time to develop.
- [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) is a native node module that allows you to interact with the ObjC runtime. I've never used it but it seems like a solid project and would simplify whatever you're trying to do. Another option similar to this is [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi). The framework you referenced looks like an ObjC API though, so not sure if that'll work for your specific use case.
- For simple stuff, you can use [node-applescript](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript). I've only played with applescript a little bit but I was surprised at some of the things you can do with it. For example, you can use it to set your app to start on login (see [node-auto-launch](https://github.com/Teamwork/node-auto-launch)). While limited compared to the above, if it does what you want, it's simpler and requires no compiling, which is nice. Note that this is going to use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) under the hood to spawn a new process to run the applescript in. That may have some ramifications to consider for whatever you're trying to do.
- You can also just use the node child_process module if the OSX API
  you're trying to use has a good CLI. The upside here is simplicity, the downside is you may have to parse the strings it outputs into meaningful data structures, which can be moderately difficult in my experience.

Comment: Your first bullet point mentions objectiveC and swift...  How can you use native modules with swift?  I only see support for C++

Comment: @CamHart hmm I thought I saw someone use Swift once. Looks like there might be a way via https://github.com/noppoMan/node-native-extension-in-swift?

Comment: https://github.com/LinusU/swift-napi-bindings seems to do the trick as well

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ffi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi) to call native libraries directly from javascript.

Comment: can node-ffi be used from electron JS ?

Comment: Yes you can. But it can be fairly complicated but it will work. You've got to remember that will only work on osx and have platform dependent solutions on other systems. Also you have to build it for electrons version not your local nodejs version, if they're different. Just like an native module.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the exec function of `child_process` to execute scripts or terminal command from you electron app.

You can also easily check on which platform your app is runnung on:

```
var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
  if(isWin){
    //windows
  }else{
    //macos
  }
```

You can also execute script that you created for OSX apps that use the OSX native API in swift after you build them:

```
 exec(path.join(__dirname, './build-scripts/Network -agr1 ' + value1 + ' -agr2 ' + value2),
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log("Fail to execute script"+ error);
        } else {
          console.log("ok")
        }
      });
```

Comment: Nitpick (sorry)...`process.platform` can only ever return: `darwin`, `freebsd`, `linux`, `sunos` or `win32`. So checking for windows is as easy as `process.platform === 'win32'`. See https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform